# Connect to Azure SQL Database using Microsoft Entra access token from Delphi using FireDAC

Tags: delphi, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, odbc, firedac

I have managed to obtain an OAuth 2 access token for authentication in Azure SQL Database. The token is definitely OK as I am able to connect using it from the Azure Portal Console.
Now I want to use the token to connect from my Delphi application using FireDAC over ODBC 18. FireDAC does not support this authentication method natively, so I have tried to add this functionality myself by editing the SetupConnection in FireDAC.Phys.ODBCBase unit as follows:

```
type
  PAccessToken = ^TAccessToken;
  TAccessToken = packed record
     dataSize: DWORD;
     data: TBytes;
   end;
...
var
 A: PAccessToken = nil;
...
procedure TFDPhysODBCConnectionBase.SetupConnection;
const
  SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN = 1256;

var
  lPrevIgnoreErrors: Boolean;
  size : DWORD;
  S : UnicodeString;
begin
  if ConnectionDef.HasValue(S_FD_ConnParam_Common_LoginTimeout) then begin
    // Old informix versions (at least 9.4 and less) do not support LOGIN_TIMEOUT
    lPrevIgnoreErrors := ODBCConnection.IgnoreErrors;
    ODBCConnection.IgnoreErrors := True;
    try
      ODBCConnection.LOGIN_TIMEOUT := ConnectionDef.AsInteger[S_FD_ConnParam_Common_LoginTimeout];
    finally
      ODBCConnection.IgnoreErrors := lPrevIgnoreErrors;
    end;
  end;

  if ConnectionDef.HasValue('AuthToken') then begin
    lPrevIgnoreErrors := ODBCConnection.IgnoreErrors;
    ODBCConnection.IgnoreErrors := True;
    try
      S := ConnectionDef.AsString['AuthToken'];
      size := Length(S)*2;

      if Assigned(A) then
       Dispose(A);

      New(A);
      A.dataSize := size;

      SetLength(A.data, A.dataSize);
      ZeroMemory(@(A.data[0]), A.dataSize);
      Move(S[1], A.data[0], A.dataSize);

      ODBCConnection.Lib.SQLSetConnectAttr(ODBCConnection.Handle, SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN, SQLPointer(A), SQL_IS_POINTER);
    finally
      ODBCConnection.IgnoreErrors := lPrevIgnoreErrors;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Unfortunately, trying to connect always returns the following error:

> [FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]Login failed for user ''

Has anyone an idea how to pass the access token properly?

Comment: The padding code in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-ver16#authenticating-with-an-access-token is missing in your code

Comment: Converting the String to UnicodeString actually produces a string with each character padded by 0. I have also tried to pad manually in a loop, but it produced the same result. What I tried was:
I := 0;
 J := 1;
 while I < size do begin
  A.data[I] := Byte(S[J]);
  A.data[I+1] := 0;

  Inc(I, 2);
  Inc(J);
 end;

Comment: Can you use a network sniffer to examine the data sent to the server on connect? (To verify the data structure does exactly match the specification.)